# Anyway to not format CSS new breakline in WebStorm for better support Flexbox Grid

Tags: css, intellij-idea, flexbox, webstorm

Is there a  way to not format CSS break lines WebStorm? Since using Flex Grid works better of multi line...

For example, this is the way I like to keep it:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .cardInner {
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "sideA"
      "sideB"
      "sideC"
      "sideD" !important;
    grid-template-columns: 99% 1%!important;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 45px) !important;
  }
  .justifyToStart {
    justify-self: normal !important;
  }

  .justifyToEnd {
    justify-self: normal !important;
  }
}

.cardInner {
  display: grid;
  //justify-content: end;
  //justify-items: end;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "sideA sideB"
    "sideC sideD";
```

But cont-alt-L will remove my Grid spaces, which is the convenient way to keep things ogranized in CSS using Flex-Grid.

Sean

Answer (score 2):

You can use formatter markers here:

- in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | Formatter Control**, tick the **Enable formatter markers in comments** checkbox
- surround your code with formatter comments:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  /*@formatter:off*/
   grid-template-areas: 
          "header header header"
           "sidebar content right"
           "footer footer footer"
  /*@formatter:on*/
}
```

We have a feature request for providing special formatting for grid-layout properties, [WEB-10013](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10013); please follow it for updates

Comment: Thank you, I will use this for now, appreciate the feedback, Sean.